# How to fix Titanium's broken menu bar on mac osx

Tags: macos, desktop-application, titanium, menubar, appcelerator

I started developing an desktop-app with Titanium Appcelerator for mac. Everything is fine except the broken menu bar. So I launch the app and get this weird looking menu bar, where every item is placed two times. I didn't create a menu, it's a default project.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of desktop are you using?  Not seeing a menu issue on Titanium 1.1 on OS 10.6.6.

Comment: I am using OSX 10.5.8... Tried it with 10.6.6 on my Macbook and there is everything fine. So it seems to be an issue of  OSX Leopard in use with Titanium 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since this was asked, but I want to contribute an answer so we can close this off:

This was fixed with Titanium Desktop 1.2.0. It was something we were doing wrong, and have since fixed.

You can read more here, if you are interested: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDESK-549

Regards,
Dawson